# Quebrar linha depois de uma IMG com CSS

Tags: css

Estou fazendo a versão mobile de um site, porem eu não consigo forçar uma quebra de linha depois de uma imagem que fica dentro de um modal.

Esse é o trecho que importa no modal:

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Açougue</h4>
</div>
<div class="row modal-conteudo">
    <div class="modal-body">

        <p>
            <img class="img-modal" src="view/img/acougue.png" align="left" style="margin-right: 10px;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer efficitur justo tellus, rutrum lobortis nibh placerat ut. Etiam magna lorem, imperdiet sit amet felis nec, dictum eleifend felis. Donec vel molestie dui. Maecenas nulla eros, porta id nulla eu, imperdiet ullamcorper purus. Pellentesque commodo, massa vitae bibendum eleifend, libero turpis dapibus elit, eu auctor nisl dui rhoncus nibh. Nam vulputate sem nisi, non eleifend justo fringilla sed. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Curabitur tincidunt lectus nisl, quis semper sem fermentum sed. Nulla a mi vehicula, sagittis nulla ac, venenatis erat. Maecenas tristique nibh eget dignissim malesuada.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basicamente eu preciso que após a tag `<img>` o css quebre a linha, mas não posso utilizar o `<br>` porque no desktop a linha não vai quebrar, somente quando a media query for `@media(max-width: 1080px)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz usando `flex` e mudando a ordem de `row` para `column`, assim fica um item por coluna. Depois usei o `align-self` para centralizar a imagem.

Veja o resultado. (vc precisa testar em uma tela menor que o Snippet aqui do StackOverflow ok)

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<style>
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1080px) {
        p {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        }
        img {
            width: 200px;
            align-self: center;
        }
    }
</style>

    
    
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Açougue</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="row modal-conteudo">
        <div class="modal-body">

            <p>
                <img class="img-modal" src="http://placecage.com/200/200" align="left" style="margin-right: 10px;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer efficitur justo tellus, rutrum lobortis nibh placerat ut. Etiam magna lorem, imperdiet sit amet felis nec, dictum eleifend felis. Donec vel molestie dui. Maecenas nulla eros, porta id nulla eu, imperdiet ullamcorper purus. Pellentesque commodo, massa vitae bibendum eleifend, libero turpis dapibus elit, eu auctor nisl dui rhoncus nibh. Nam vulputate sem nisi, non eleifend justo fringilla sed. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Curabitur tincidunt lectus nisl, quis semper sem fermentum sed. Nulla a mi vehicula, sagittis nulla ac, venenatis erat. Maecenas tristique nibh eget dignissim malesuada.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**OBS:** *Se vc estiver como o Bootstrap 4 é ainda melhor pq ele já tem o Grid em Flex e todas as classes do Flex nativas.*

Comment: Simples e funcional! Muito obrigado

Comment: @OtavioSouzaRocha valeu jovem. Só mais uma coisa, vc também pode testar fazer essa quebra usando o Grid do próprio Bootstrap, Ai vc tem que separar a imagem e o P, cada um em uma div, tipo `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">` para a imagem e `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">` para o texto. Boa sorte com o projeto. Tmj

Comment: Eu geralmente utilizo o Bootstrap, mas nesse caso eu o site vai sem consideravelmente diferente no mobile, ai decidi fazer com media query

Answer (score 1):

Ele não quebra pois tem o `align="left"`. Minha sugestão é: remove `align="left"`, adiciona a imagem dentro de uma div com uma classe com `float:left` e quando for menor que "tal", apenas remove o float left:

```css
@media screen and (min-width:765px){
  .float-left-lg{
    float:left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">       
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Açougue</h4>
</div>
<div class="row modal-conteudo">
    <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="float-left-lg"><img class="img-modal" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" style="margin-right: 10px;"></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer efficitur justo tellus, rutrum lobortis nibh placerat ut. Etiam magna lorem, imperdiet sit amet felis nec, dictum eleifend felis. Donec vel molestie dui. Maecenas nulla eros, porta id nulla eu, imperdiet ullamcorper purus. Pellentesque commodo, massa vitae bibendum eleifend, libero turpis dapibus elit, eu auctor nisl dui rhoncus nibh. Nam vulputate sem nisi, non eleifend justo fringilla sed. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Curabitur tincidunt lectus nisl, quis semper sem fermentum sed. Nulla a mi vehicula, sagittis nulla ac, venenatis erat. Maecenas tristique nibh eget dignissim malesuada.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa é colocar o texto dentro de outra tag `<p>`:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <p>
        <img class="img-modal" src="view/img/acougue.png" align="left" style="margin-right: 10px;">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer efficitur justo tellus, rutrum lobortis nibh placerat ut. Etiam magna lorem, imperdiet sit amet felis nec, dictum eleifend felis. Donec vel molestie dui. Maecenas nulla eros, porta id nulla eu, imperdiet ullamcorper purus. Pellentesque commodo, massa vitae bibendum eleifend, libero turpis dapibus elit, eu auctor nisl dui rhoncus nibh. Nam vulputate sem nisi, non eleifend justo fringilla sed. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Curabitur tincidunt lectus nisl, quis semper sem fermentum sed. Nulla a mi vehicula, sagittis nulla ac, venenatis erat. Maecenas tristique nibh eget dignissim malesuada.
        </p>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Sim, porém nesse caso, quando o site for aberto pelo desktop a imagem vai estar com a linha quebrada também, preciso que quebre só no mobile